# PayUmoney iOS SDK multiple issues during uploading app on apple store with XCODE9.3(Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, payumoney, xcode9.3

Errors:

> 1.ITMS-90087 Unsupported Archtecture  PayUmoneyCoreSDK.framework containts unsupported architectures '[x86_64,i386]' also for
>   CitrusGraphics and PlugNPlay framework.
>
> 2.ITMS-90209 Invalid Segment Alignment  CitrusGraphics does not have proper segment also for PlugNPlay and PayUmoneyCoreSDK framework.
>
> 3.ITMS-90125 The Binary is invalid "The incryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid or the
>   binary is already encrypted.This binary does not seem to have been
>   built with Apple's linker"
>
> Warnings:
>   1.ITMS-90080 PayUMoneyCoreSDK.framwork is not a position Independent Executable.Please ensure that your build setting are configured to
>   create PIE executables.

I removed above framework from Embedded Binaries then uploaded to app store.Its uploaded successfully but app store rejected app because above libraries image not found issue and app crash initially.

I took support from PayUmoney they suggested to again integrate iOS SDK.I did that but still issue is there.

And someone please told why this is happening? Becasue last year  old iOS SDK worked fine.Once I integrated new update for XCODE 9 then issue will raise. I worked with objective-C and XCODE 9.3

Here is updated iOS SDK link :https://github.com/payu-intrepos/PayUMoney-IOS-SDK/tree/master/PlugNPlay/Objective-C%20SampleApp

I attached some snippet of issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dV8Scc2K47o-V9lhVLSCl46o_cMxA6x0/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17P5ZCegveF2xdq73AEwuX0Wqwr6h68fP/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xAB0WH1zLlqCRQxEbROVmRBP4TngkEzM/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10gPbOd9fwsMKj_RAqNRexcU6OUNFsgOn/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KsP7QtvRoPVSCMNAAt9JGDmJEUBfDaH7/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eXkCvGQU_7fnFJy136jV0S8YkI8Fpvqn/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oU1TfIwpKQx_dx1eD2nFwmmiAPjKudsu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try this to remove unwanted architectures [stripping-unwanted-architectures](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/). Not sure but may be it helps you.

Comment: @Mehul Sojitra Thanks for response .I read Article.I will check.

Comment: Are running this in device or simulator ? actually . x86_64 is for simulator  did you try in device ?

Comment: Running on device is work well ,getting issue during archive uploaded to  app store

Comment: @Mehul Sojitra Great!! This article solution fixed All issues.You save my  day...Thank you so much.Now I am waiting for app review status.

Comment: Welcome @VinayakBhor

Comment: @Mehul Sojitra Finally app is live.Shell script works well.You are the saviour man.Thanks again.

Comment: Congratulations @VinayakBhor. Good Luck for your app. Always ready for help.

Comment: I'm facing error as below when using that shell script
line 4: z: command not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127

Comment: @jaya raj which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.2

Comment: @jaya raj please share your error screenshots.

Comment: I created 3 script for 3 frameworks. now it's woking. Thank you so much

Comment: @jaya raj Great! Only one script needed .All the best !